# Is there any way to extract and print a raw/literal string from a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code in Python 3.0 to reformat a data file line by line. The code reads each line, converts the line into a list, then reads each element of the list. Each list element is then modified and copied to an output file.

The problem is that some of the elements contain backslash characters, which Python will interpret as commands or inexplicably ignore. Is there any way in Python to read and/or extract the elements of a list as raw or literal strings?

My code is below:

```
import shlex
import sys
import fileinput
import string
inputFile = list(open("inputfile.txt","r"))
outputFile = open("outputFile.txt","a")

for i in range(1,len(inputFile)):
    print(inputFile[i])
    line = shlex.shlex(inputFile[i], posix = True)
    line.whitespace = "\t"
    line.whitespace_split = True
    line = list(line)
    for j in range(0,3):
        cell = line[j]
        cell_1 = cell.replace("\\","\\\\")
        outputFile .write(("%s\t")%(cell_1))
    for k in range(4,len(line)):
        cell = str(line[k])
        cell_1 = cell.replace(" | ","\t")
        if cell_1 == "-":
            outputFile .write("-\t-\t")
        if cell_1 == "unknown":
            outputFile .write("unknown\t-\t")
        else:
            outputFile .write(("%s\t")%(cell_1))
```

An example of the input is:
GA10034 7421353 7424287 FBgn0070093 Dpse\GA10034    proteolysis | inferred from electronic annotation with InterPro:IPR007484   -   -   -   -   unknown -   -   -   peptidase activity | inferred from electronic annotation with InterPro:IPR007484    -   -   -   -
-   -

And an example output line is:
    GA10034 7421353 7424287 DpseGA10034 proteolysis inferred from electronic annotation with InterPro:IPR007484 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   unknown -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   peptidase activity  inferred from electronic annotation with InterPro:IPR007484 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -

The \ between Dpse and GA10034 is deleted in the output.

(The script is also adding a tab character at the start of each new line - starting from the second line - in the output; and is inexplicable failing about 3/4 of the way through the input file claiming that there is "no closing quotation"; but I thought it was best to address one problem at a time)

Comment: Can you add an example with an input and the desired output?

Comment: So... what's your actual problem? What's the expected output, and how does it compare to the actual output? You'll get a lot more attention if you actually show us what problems you're seeing. Honestly, it looks to me like you might just be overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you are specifying `posix = True` when creating your parser, which interprets backslashes and quotes. However, it sounds like you don't want those behaviors, so you should use `posix = False` instead.